# What does "AUTO_INCREMENT=416" in a CREATE TABLE statement mean?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL databases that I'm checking for differences and then making changes where necessary to make them the same.
When I run the `mysqldiff` against these two tables it shows that one has

ENGINE=MyISAM **AUTO_INCREMENT=416** DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

While the other doesn't

```
~$ mysqldiff --force --server1=root@localhost prod_si.si_payment:dev_si_brand_new.si_payment
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing prod_si.si_payment to dev_si_brand_new.si_payment      [FAIL]
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- prod_si.si_payment
+++ dev_si_brand_new.si_payment
@@ -9,4 +9,4 @@
   `online_payment_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`,`id`),
   KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`)
-) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=416 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
+) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I've looked at the values entered in the tables, and can't see any obvious differences, i.e. the primary keys that have auto_increment designations are both automatically increasing by 1 per row. [Increment amount](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) seems to be a different directive.
I've looked at the [mysql auto_increment documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) and can't find anything there.

What does `AUTO_INCREMENT=416` do?

Comment: its the next value for your auto_increment field. it is different between your tables, because they have different amounts of data in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a table option.  It sets the initial value for the auto increment column.

The documentation is a bit tricky to find, but [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) it is:

> To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value
>   with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:
>
> mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;

Comment: Interesting, I tested the statement and it doesn't seem to make any difference on my MySQL 5.5 install. As you mentioned it seems to be applied on the table rather than columns. Does this mean it's a default property that newly created columns "inherit" from the table, but columns that are already establish with their own properties are set and cannot be changed - because the column itself cant have that attribute modified?

Comment: @user4668401 . . . It is a property on the table for the next auto increment value.  Existing data does not change.

Comment: yes, thats what I understood it it be, what I should have said in my comment was - *"I tested it by altering a table and applying `AUTO_INCREMENT=<value>`  property, and also by creating a table from scratch with the property - in either case - the auto_increment fields in new records didn't start at the expected `<value>`"*. Im going to assume that there was some detail I was missing in my implementation which is beyond the scope of this question - and that the documentation is correct. It just would have been nice to actually *confirm* it to be true :)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you've linked:

```
To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

It will only affect new rows inserted in a table, if you have an auto incrementing column.